# Irritating review number in the toolbar

Tags: support

I can see reviews as `4` always even when there are no reviews to be reviewed. As the days goes on, the review number is getting incremented but not disappearing. I strongly think this is a bug.

PS: I am reloading the page frequently by clicking on the review number. Still no use.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, it annoys me too.  I find that it happens more often when I click "skip" on a review task.  Maybe the algorithm calculates the total number of review tasks it has in its queue, regardless of whether it's already shown some of them to you or not.

Comment: I have the same problem. I have been a member of the Philosophy SE for longer then Hinduism SE and I don't have the same problem on Philosophy SE. Mine was at 3, now it's at 14. And nothing to review. It has to be a bug.

Comment: [status-bydesign](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/tags/status-bydesign/info)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The number in the top bar (for folks with [access to moderator tools](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)) is the **total** number of pending review tasks in the system.

That means every review task that hasn't yet been completed contributes to it - *not* just the ones you haven't looked at yet. If *you're* reviewing but that number doesn't drop - or goes up - then there's a problem...

[image]

...some other folks on the site aren't keeping up. If this is temporary, and only happens occasionally, don't worry about it; but if it's a regular thing, or that number *keeps* climbing, you might want to encourage your fellow members to help carry some of the weight.